# How to retrieve original url in a redirected page using PHP

Tags: php

Let say I have redirect rule on url **example.com** which redirect to **newurl.net**. 
How can I get original url on ***newurl.net*** in order to be used and handled with some details or just to be printed on new destination.

Thank anyone for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the 'referer' header in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031162/how-do-you-get-the-referer-header-in-php)

Comment: The referrer is unreliable, you might not get one at all, or a faked/manipulated one. If you want this to work properly, then you need to put the info you want to transport into the URL you are redirecting to to begin with, so that you can read it from there at the target.

Comment: So, the only way possible will be to pass a parameter (i.e. example.com?dom=newurl) and $_GET['dom'] to retrieve the url

Comment: Parameter or session seems like your best choice

Answer (score 1):

If it's not external You can use

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

And it will give you the referer which is what you want.

See [Acquiring referral after a PHP redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282732/acquiring-referral-url-after-a-php-redirect) for more informations.

But if you are trying to get to another website, the browser will overwrite the headers so you need to do it some other way.

You can store it in **session**.

```
//Save it in your first website
$_SESSION['REFERER'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

And then in the other website :

```
//Use it in the other
$referer = '';
if (isset($_SESSION['REFERER'])) {
    $referer = $_SESSION['REFERER'];
    unset($_SESSION['REFERER']);
}
```

You could also pass the referer as a **parameter**:

```
header('Location: http://newurl.net?original_referer=' .$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Comment: I think this will not work as will get server informatin only regarding new location newurl.com

Comment: You may want to store it session then or with a parameter then,

Comment: The point is that the original url is only domain, no hosting. Starting point will be example.com redirect to newurl.com. Do not have host on example.com.